# Версия VkAPI не меняется при передаче соответствующего параметра v в запросе

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api

Когда делаю запрос на список сообщений из беседы дает ошибку на параметре "peer_id". Оказалось, что даже если я передаю "v":5.38, то версия, которую мне возвращают в error коде гораздо меньше и в ней не поддерживается этот параметр. Что делать в такой ситуации?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отвечу на этот достаточно старый вопрос. Тогда в Java SDK был баг, в котором независимо от переданной версии в API посылалсь некоторая захардкоженная версия, из-за чего и было несоответствие.

Answer (score 0):

А какой метод api вы используете?
Получать сообщения можно через метод [messages.getConversations](https://vk.com/dev/messages.getConversations) в котором нет никакого параметра peer_id. Этот метод возвращает вам ВСЕ сообщения, в том числе из беседы. А вот потом можно определять, после получения, от кого это сообщение - от пользователя из беседы или личное сообщение.

Comment: Использую messages.getHistory. Насколько я понимаю getConversations возвращает объекты диалога, а мне требуются объекты сообщений для беседы с ее id.

Comment: Вот пример запроса:  VKRequest request = new VKRequest("messages.getHistory?peer_id="+String.valueOf(id)+"&v=5.65");  Вот ответ: E/apierror.requestParams: [{value=1, key=oauth}, {value=messages.getHistory, key=method}, {value=2000000143, key=peer_id}, {value=5.21, key=v}, {value=ru, key=lang}, {value=1, key=https}]

Comment: messages.getConversations  возвращает В ТОМ ЧИСЛЕ беседу

Comment: Это понятно, я не отрицаю. Из getConversation я получаю список диалогов(в том числе бесед). Теперь при нажатии на беседу требуется получить список сообщений из беседы. По описанию метода getHistory он именно это и делает. Но с ним есть проблема описанная в топике.